# Tips and/or suggestions to install Silverlight on Mac Computers

Tags: macos, silverlight, installation, multimedia, pivotviewer

All:

Our ASP.NET C# web application is used in the following environment

```
.NET Framework 4

Silverlight 4 ( with PivotViewer )

IIS 7

Windows 2008

Visual Studio 2010
```

.NET IDE

```
C#

HTTPS ( SSL )
```

The Mac users of our application usually have trouble with installing Silverlight.
For some Silverlight installs in the Mac with ease.  However, most people have to install silverlight, and restart the machine a number of times.

It's so unpredictable how Silverlight installs on the Macs.

In a lot of the cases a mac user has to separately install Silverlight for the various browsers ( i.e. FireFox, Safari and Chrome ).

Moreover, Silverlight might only start working after the user restarts the Mac after a number of times.

-----For users who have Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) or a higher version of Mac Operating Systems------
The Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) and higher versions of Mac Operating Systems seem to have the feature called "Resume" which ensures that the Mac system will
recall the state of applications and files just before you quit which would allow you to open them up again, and just pick up from where you left off.

However, the "Resume" feature may be a stumbling block when it comes to installing Silverlight.

Therefore, it might be a good idea if we turn off the "Resume" feature temporarily in order to install Silverlight.

If you have a Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) or a higher version of Mac Operating Systems then go to the Mac OS's System Preference.
Go to "General" Tab within System Preferences.
Ensure that the checkbox for "Restore windows when quitting and re-opening apps." is unchecked.

### After installing Silverlight, and ensuring that the Silverlight/Pivot Viewer in Perls Web Application shows up properly, you could check the checkbox for "Restore windows when quitting and re-opening apps." if you want the "Resume" feature for your Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) or a higher version of Mac Operating Systems

------Some of my colleagues also gave the following steps but it only worked for some Mac Users therefore it's still unpredictable--------------------------------------------------
Mac User might have to install Silverlight, uninstall silverlight, and then install silverlight again.

Mac users usually had a problem with our Silverlight/Pivot Viewer component  within our Web Application.

if the Mac User already has Silverlight installed on his Mac but has problems using the Silverlight/Pivot Viewer component  within our Web Application then kindly take the following steps in Removing Silverlight plugins on Macintosh:

- Access your hard drive
- Double-click the hard drive icon on your
  desktop
- Find the plugin by Navigating to your Internet Plug-Ins directory:
  /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/
- Remove the plugin  by Dragging any of the
  following into your trash bin:
  a) Silverlight.plugin
  b) WPFe.plugin

-Just quit all applications, and then shutdown your Mac, and then start up your Mac again.

-Open up Safari browser in Mac.

-In general, Safari on Macs place entities downloaded from the internet on to the following directory

/Users/blah blah your Mac LoginID folder blah blah/Downloads/

1. However, if you want to configure where downloads by Safari on Macs should be placed then Click on the "Safari" menu on the Main Menu of the Mac computer.
2. When the drop-down menu shows up, make sure that you select the "Preferences……" option.
3. A new Window should show up with the title "General"
4. There should be a drop-down box with the Label "Save downloaded files to:" within the Window
5. Using drop-down box with the Label "Save downloaded files to:", we can configure where we want Safari to placed Downloaded entities.
6. click the Save Downloaded Files To show the drop-down menu and choose Other.
7. Navigate to and select the location where you want the files stored and click Select.
8. Click the Close button to exit Preferences.
9. The folder you chose will now be the default location for anything you download from the Internet.

-lets start off by entering the url called http://www.microsoft.com/ on the Safari browser.

-On the Microsoft Website, search for "download Silverlight for mac"
-Click on the Relevant link associated with getting Silverlight
-Try to download the Silverlight component

It is important to note that we found that for the Silverlight installation needed for the Silverlight/Pivot Viewer component within our Web Application, we needed to ensure that you quit all browsers on the Mac before the installation of Silverlight.

-Ensure that you quit out of all browsers.

-Just quit all applications, and then shutdown your Mac, and then start up your Mac again.

-Ensure that you quit out of all browsers.

-Navigate to the folder where Safari places Downloaded files:
-Click on the Silverlight installation file ( should be a file with the extension pkg or it might be file with extension dmg which contains the file with extension pkg.)
-Run the installation.

-Navigate to Web application Website

### -Login, and try to see if the Silverlight/Pivot Viewer shows up properly.

Does anyone know straightforward steps, tips or suggestions taken to install Silverlight on Mac computers?  If so, could you please list it out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One of my colleagues installed Silverlight on his Mac for the very first time, and nothing worked in any of the browsers.  He then took the following steps: - downloaded silverlight
- noted the instructions for uninstalling
- quit all browsers
- did the uninstall
- installed silverlight

Comment: from experience the important thing is once you have done the install Quit (Apple-Q) all browsers, don't just close the browser windows. You have to fully unload the things to get the plugin to register properly.

Comment: @Offbeatmammal We noticed that it was important to Quit all Browser "Before" running the installation of Silverlight ( Not during installation or after installation) It is important to note that we found that for the Silverlight installation needed for the Silverlight/Pivot Viewer component within our Web Application, we needed to ensure that you quit all browsers on the Mac before the installation of Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaned up the info from your post a bit:

The Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) and higher versions of Mac Operating Systems seem to have the feature called "Resume" which ensures that the Mac system will recall the state of applications and files just before you quit which would allow you to open them up again, and just pick up from where you left off.

However, the "Resume" feature may be a stumbling block when it comes to installing Silverlight.

Therefore, it might be a good idea if we turn off the "Resume" feature temporarily in order to install Silverlight.

If you have a Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion) or a higher version of Mac Operating Systems then go to the Mac OS's System Preference. Go to "General" Tab within System Preferences. Ensure that the checkbox for "Restore windows when quitting and re-opening apps." is unchecked.

(after successful installation you can go and select that option again at the OS)

---

If the Mac User already has Silverlight installed but has problems using the Silverlight component take the following steps in Removing Silverlight plugins on Macintosh:
• Double-click the hard drive icon on your desktop 
• Find the plugin by Navigating to your Internet Plug-Ins directory: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/ 
• Remove the plugin by Dragging any of the following into your trash bin:
a) Silverlight.plugin
b) WPFe.plugin

---

Ensure that you quit all browsers on the Mac before the installation of Silverlight.

-Ensure that you quit out of all browsers.

-Just quit all applications, and then shutdown your Mac, and then start up your Mac again.

-Navigate to the folder where your browser places Downloaded files: 
  -Click on the Silverlight installation file ( should be a file with the extension pkg or it might be file with extension dmg which contains the file with extension pkg.) 
  -Run the installation.